# Exception raised with simple esRDD (elasticsearch-hadoop connector used in Spark)

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I am testing ElasticSearch and Spark integration (with elasticsearch-hadoop connector) on localhost, using some test data loaded in elasticsearch. Invoking interactive shell:

```
] $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --jars ~/spark/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.2.0.jar --conf spark.es.nodes="localhost" spark.es.port="9200" spark.es.resource="myindex/mytype"

scala> import org.elasticsearch.spark._
scala> val my_rdd = sc.esRDD("myindex/mytype")

my_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef])] = ScalaEsRDD[0] at RDD at AbstractEsRDD.scala:34
```

But the following action threws an exception and makes Spark exits:

```
scala> my_rdd.take(3).foreach(println)

17/02/02 14:08:18 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.<init>(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:28)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.ScalaEsRDDIterator.<init>(ScalaEsRDD.scala:43)
at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.ScalaEsRDD.compute(ScalaEsRDD.scala:39)
...
...
Driver stacktrace:))

]
```

Versions: 
ES : 2.4.2
Spark : 2.0.1
elasticsearch-hadoop: 5.2.0

Could it be a conflict between versions? Is there a way to test the ES connection without elasticsearch-hadoop connector?
Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Spark 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. So
you need to download elastic search spark connector for 2.0 which build against Scala 2.11.

You can download it from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11/5.1.2).

Comment: The link that you provided refers to es-hadoop 5.1.2. Do you mean that the version I used (5.2.0) is not compatible with spark 2.0.1?

Comment: Its not es-hadoop instead it is es-spark. Download the file you will understand the difference!

Comment: Sorry I'm not at my desk right now. Is es-spark and es-hadoop offer the same functionalities? Are they complementary or concurrent products?

Comment: es-hadoop is combined connector of all big data technologies like Hadoop, Spark, Storm, Pig. ..etc. where as es-spark is sub project of es-hadoop which only supports Spark.

Comment: So maybe es-hadoop is too big for my needs but in my understanding it should work, am I wrong?

Comment: Just tried it and it works with the elasticsearch-spark connector you provided. Thank you.